# Segmentation Fault in C, possibly on medium/large dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

**NOTE:** I have looked at other segmentation fault postings, and the ones that relate closely to my problem are when large arrays are created on the stack eventually causing an overflow.  However, as you can see from the code below, I am allocating on the heap and still encountering this problem.

I have used both Valgrind and gdb to debug this, and they tell me the following: There's an "Invalid read of size 4 ... numberDivisors" or segmentation fault occurring in the function code below.  The odd thing is, this works for all numbers up to 49141 after it loops through the numbers of interest when it will either throw the error or segfault.  **This is only when it is in a loop.**  When I put in a single large number without looping, it will report back the number of divisors without erring out or segfault-ing.  Can anyone see what the problem is in the code below?  Thanks!

```
int numberDivisors(int n) {
    int lim = (int)floor(sqrt((double)n));
    int *primes = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    int *divisors = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    int i, j, ctr;
    ctr = 0;

    if(primes && divisors) {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            primes[i] = 1;
            divisors[i] = 0;
        }

        for(i = 2; i < lim; i++) {
            if(primes[i]) {
                for(j = i; i * j < n; j++) {
                    primes[i * j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        for(i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if(primes[i]) {
                if(n % i == 0) divisors[i] = 1;
                for(j = i; i * j < n; j++) {
                    // int result = n % (i * j);
                    assert(i * j < n); //Added at lsk's request.  i * j passes the test.

                    //if(result == 0) {
                    if(n % (i * j) == 0) {
                        if(!divisors[i * j]) {
                            divisors[i * j] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if(divisors[i]) ctr++;
        }

        ctr += 2;
    } else {
        printf("Allocation failed.");
    }
    free(primes);
    free(divisors);
    return ctr;
}
```

**UPDATE**  I changed all the int's in the function to unsigned long (just to see that it would work), and it's running just fine now.  However, Umer is right - I have to rethink the algorithm because it takes longer than is necessary, but that is another question all together.  Thank you for the assistance SO community!

Comment: Which line is the problem in? The only suspicious code I see is that i*j is being used as an index and it may be greater than the allocated size. Can you add an assert() to check such conditions? Please add <assert.h> to your code.

Comment: Every time he uses i*j, it's inside a loop block with the condition i*j < n, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @lsk The code is updated with an assertion.  The test gets passed.  The interesting thing is, I am in agreement with Filipe's comments, but don't know where else the problem could be.

Comment: Cannot reproduce here. Have you tried separating this function to new program for testing?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: `i * j < n` does not imply that `i * j >= 0`, see my answer below.

Comment: Not getting any segmentation fault. Tried it on codeblocks and on other online compilers. Try to create a new .c file and compile this program there. This should solve this problem

Comment: Changing the condition in the `for` loop to `j < n / i` avoids arithmetic overflow (and dividing by `i` rather than `j` leaves the optimizer room to optimize.  As long as you're dividing by a positive integer, integer division can't overflow.

Comment: @harpun Good point! Very good answer. I didn't think about overflow. Nice one! Beautiful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in fact in

```
if(!divisors[i * j]) {
   divisors[i * j] = 1;
}
```

due to integer overflow. Consider a simple example:

```
int n = 123123123;
int i = 57641;
int j = 74495;

printf("i         = %d\n", i);
printf("j         = %d\n", j);
printf("i * j     = %d\n", i*j);
printf("i*1.0 * j = %f\n", i*1.0 * j);
printf("n         = %d\n", n);
```

which produces the following output:

```
i         = 57641
j         = 74495
i * j     = -1001001
i*1.0 * j = 4293966295.000000
n         = 123123123
```

as you can see `i * j < n` is true, but `i * j` is a negative integer. Indexing `divisors` with a negative index causes the crash.

Comment: I fully concur that this is where the problem is.  In a `gdb` session where I was testing 50059, I got: `(gdb) p divisors` and
`$1 = (int *) 0x100034000` (so `divisors` was OK), then
`(gdb) p i` and
$2 = 47653` (which could be fine), and
`(gdb) p j` and
`$3 = 90129` (which is absolutely not fine).  I got different the crash at different values of `n` on different machines.